# How to check if a directory is empty or not in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Given a directory, how can I check if it is empty or not. I can do that in userspace(using functions like opendir and readdir and equivalent dirent structures) but how should I do in kernel space?

Comment: Note that you will need to lock the directory's inode while you do whatever you are doing based on the answer, because otherwise the answer could change out from under you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the source code for openndir and readdir you find they eventually call API calls getdents(). Read the source code for the system call getdents() for your answer. If you're on the application side of the VFS layer (trying to call from lower layers will end up in deadlock), you should be able to replicate the getdents loop from the VFS inode handle of the directory calling into the VFS layer. I did it once a long time ago.